# Multiply the row of two matrix to obtain a scalar with Fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran95

After a few years of not using Fortran I'm having some troubles with `matmul`. Suppose I have two matrix: A_{N,K} and B_{J,K} . I want to create a subroutine that takes a row of A and a row of B, multiplies that and creates the scalar C. This is what I wrote:

```
subroutine test_matmul(A, B, N, K, J, row_a, row_b, C)
  integer, intent(in)                                   :: N, K, J, row_a, row_b
  double precision, dimension(N,K), intent(in)          :: A
  double precision, dimension(J,K), intent(in)          :: B
  double precision, intent(out)                         :: C

  C = matmul(A(row_a,:), B(row_b,:))

end subroutine test_matmul
```

Alas, when I try to compile this I get the following error:

```
  C = matmul(A(row_a,:), B(row_b,:))
                         1
Error: 'matrix_b' argument of 'matmul' intrinsic at (1) must be of rank 2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is clear `matmul` multiplies two matrices and you are trying to pass two vectors. If you convert the vectors to matrices, `matmul` will through another error about matrices dimensions mismatch.

You should try using `dot_product(vector_a, vector_b)` instead of `matmul`.